# Composer update Drupal core, 8.5.1 to 8.5.2 Nothing to Install

Tags: 8, composer

I am running Drupal 8.5.1, with `php 7.2` and a new security update 8.5.2 was just released. Per the documentation, I should be able to update Drupal core with composer.

I ran the following command:

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

I keep getting :

> Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files
>   Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
>   Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess

Has anyone have any luck updating a drupal site with composer? I usually update my Drupal sites manually but this is getting tiring. I do not trust drush for my updates.

Comment: I am running composer version  1.6.3, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to delete the `vendor` directory and the `composer.lock` file, and then run the update again.

UPDATE:

- You need to add the line "drupal/core": "~8.5.2" to the 'require' statement (or update it to whatever version you require).
- Then remove the drupal/core line from the 'replace' statement.
- Add the following line somewhere (at the end? I believe this should replace the existing repositories statement):

  "repositories": { 
    "drupal": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8" 
    }
  }

Then delete the vendor and composer.lock, and try again.

It should work.

Comment: I removed the vendor folder and the compose.lock file and rerun the command  but that did NOT work.

Comment: Try to look at the update

Comment: I followed your update directives: 1 i added this line to the require section: "drupal/core": "^8.5.2" . 2. I removed the 'replace' statement and i already had the repositories set. 3. I deleted the vendor folder and composer.lock. and Voila it got the new updates. Thanks @jdrupal

Comment: Nuking vendor and lockfile seems like a last resort IMO. This was probably a version specification mismatch.